# Extract XML from CLOB to later on save the XML file with SPOOL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsqldeveloper

i have this SQL script:

```
SELECT
  DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML (
    'SELECT df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
     df.bytes / (1024 * 1024) "Size (MB)",
      SUM(fs.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) "Free (MB)",
       Nvl(Round(SUM(fs.bytes) * 100 / df.bytes),1) "Free(%)",
        Round((df.bytes - SUM(fs.bytes)) * 100 / df.bytes) "Used (%)" FROM dba_free_space fs,
         (SELECT tablespace_name,
         SUM(bytes) bytes FROM dba_data_files GROUP BY tablespace_name) df
          WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,df.bytes
           UNION ALL SELECT df.tablespace_name tspace, fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024), SUM(df.bytes_free) / (1024 * 1024),
            Nvl(Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_used) * 100 / fs.bytes), 1), Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_free) * 100 / fs.bytes)
             FROM dba_temp_files fs, (SELECT tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used FROM v$temp_space_header
              GROUP BY tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used) df
               WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,fs.bytes,df.bytes_free,df.bytes_used
                ORDER BY 4'
  ) AS data
FROM DUAL;
```

It creates a CLOB with nice and formatted XML inside it. But what I would like is to using SQLPLUS and SPOOL - export this XML file. But because of the fact that the output of this script is CLOB with XML inside it, it does not work. Does anyone know how to change this script so instead of having a CLOB i would get this XML?

Comment: Please clarify a meaning of "doesn't work": what the errors do you have or what is wrong with the data? There's no any difference between spooling an arbitrary text or XML, because XML is just a text

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your clob to XMLTYPE using XMLTYPE() function:

```sql
SPOOL your_drive:\your_folder_path\your_file_name.xml 
    SELECT
        XMLTYPE(    -- XMLTYPE() function
          DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML (
            'SELECT df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
             df.bytes / (1024 * 1024) "Size (MB)",
              SUM(fs.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) "Free (MB)",
               Nvl(Round(SUM(fs.bytes) * 100 / df.bytes),1) "Free(%)",
                Round((df.bytes - SUM(fs.bytes)) * 100 / df.bytes) "Used (%)" FROM dba_free_space fs,
                 (SELECT tablespace_name,
                 SUM(bytes) bytes FROM dba_data_files GROUP BY tablespace_name) df
                  WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,df.bytes
                   UNION ALL SELECT df.tablespace_name tspace, fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024), SUM(df.bytes_free) / (1024 * 1024),
                    Nvl(Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_used) * 100 / fs.bytes), 1), Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_free) * 100 / fs.bytes)
                     FROM dba_temp_files fs, (SELECT tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used FROM v$temp_space_header
                      GROUP BY tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used) df
                       WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,fs.bytes,df.bytes_free,df.bytes_used
                        ORDER BY 4'
      )  ) AS data  -- data column is now of type XMLTYPE
    FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF
```

Or even better (as commented by ***astentx***), you can use DBMS_XMLGEN.**getXMLTYPE()** instead of DBMS_XMLGEN.genXML() result for both is the same...
The file looks like this:
[image]

Comment: XMLType instance may be produced directly with `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype()` function without extra conversion

Comment: @astentx Correct. Just put it in the answer, thanks.